# Vb.net word select all

Tags: vb.net, ctrl

I am choosing one or more characters in my string and I want to cut  select characters.(CTRL+X) How can I do it?

For Example : "Hello Everybody"

I select "body " section in word .

And  how can I do Ctrl + F , Ctrl + H , Ctrl + G ?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you I find it solution :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your solution so that it may help future visitors

Comment: here what is `CTRL + G` stands for?

Comment: I found Ctrl + X and I research other subject. My Code : 
 ` If RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0 Then
 MsgBox("Please choose string") 
Else RichTextBox1.Text = Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.SelectedText, "")
 End If`